# Construct an example where the KMP algorithm has to backtrack multiple times

Tags: python, string, algorithm

I'm trying to construct an example where the [kmp algorithm](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/searching-for-patterns-set-2-kmp-algorithm/) `computeLPSArray` phase will have to backtrack (see comment below) multiple times for a certain i (cell in the LPS array).

e.g. for `'AAACAAA'` it visits the backtrack section twice for `i = 3` and once for `i = 7`

Can you help me construct a string where it will visit the backtrack section 3-4 times for a certain `i`?

```
def computeLPSArray(pat, M, lps):
    len = 0 # length of the previous longest prefix suffix
    lps[0]=0 # lps[0] is always 0
    i = 1
    while i < M:
    if pat[i]==pat[len]:
        len+=1
        lps[i] = len
        i+=1
    else:
        if len!=0:
            # backtrack section - When will we get here 3-4 times for the same i??? 
            len = lps[len-1]     
        else:
            lps[i] = 0
            i+=1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `'AAAACAA'` it visits the backtrack section 3 times for `i = 4`.

With `'AAAAACA'` it visits the backtrack section 4 times for `i = 5`.

Comment: oh great. Can you please also show me how to construct an example where backtrack happens several times but len doesn't reach 0? (I know I'm asking a lot here, I just can't wrap my head around this algorithm and looking for examples to make it clearer). Thanks!!

Comment: @ihadanny: With `'ABAABABAABABAABABAABAAA'` it backtracks three times for `i=21`, but len only goes down to 3, not 0 (it starts at 16, backtracks to 11, then 6, then 3.) It stops at 3 because `pat[3]` is `A`, which agrees with `pat[21]`, which broke the prefix-matching pattern.

Answer (score 1):

As you already mentioned: your example string `AAACAAA` already visited the backtrack section 2 times when `i = 3`.

If you want to increase the number of visits, increase the numbers of `A` in the prefix, e.g.

```
AAAAC
```

will visit the backtrack section 3 times.